# Logback Configuration: Two appenders, logging based on package

Tags: logback

I'm trying to configure logback so that certain packages are logged differently depending on the appender.  I have a `ConsoleAppender` and a `RollingFileAppender`.  I want `TRACE` level logging for the `ConsoleAppender` and I want only two packages logged to the `RollingFileAppender`.  What ends up happening is my `ConsoleAppender` and `RollingFileAppender` behave exactly the same.

Here is my `logback.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration>
    <property resource="logback.properties" />

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>.%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="dailyRollingFileAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <file>${logback.dir}${logback.filename}.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${logback.dir}${logback.filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

            <!-- keep 90 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="x.y" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="dailyRollingFileAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="TRACE" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is quite similar to the question I just asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086304/package-specific-logging-levels-for-different-logback-appenders
The difference is that on a specific appender you want to log only two packages, while I want default logging levels on everything *except* some packages. Did you make any progress on your problem?