# How to disable any kind of logging from dependency in maven? [ logback,ethereumJ]

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, logback, ethereumj

**Is there a way to disable all internal logging in this dependency (ethereumj) ?**

Currently seems like its still loggin something.

What i did to combat this was exclude logback dependency **(Im using maven)** :

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ethereum/ethereumj-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ethereum</groupId>
        <artifactId>ethereumj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0-RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-parent</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Bud when i look at unstaged files  I can still see **logs/ethereum.log** So looks like this logback is still active maybe its included from another dependency. Do i have to go thru all dependencies i have and look for internal dependencies if logback is present or is there some better way?

[image]

Comment: In logback.xml, you can disable logging from packages.

Comment: @Sambit Ah ok so i have to explicitly create config file for this, Can I forbid project wide logback logging?

Comment: In your existing logback.xml file, write the package names from which you do not want to see the loggings.

Comment: You can refer below the old stackoverflow links.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397442/disable-the-log-from-specific-class-jar-via-logback-xml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086304/package-specific-logging-levels-for-different-logback-appenders?rq=1

Comment: @Sambit I also want to prevent from the ethereum.log file from beign created, is that possible within that configuration?

Comment: May be, ethereum jar file has the log configuration to log the details. I do not know, but you search. However, you can minimize the logging by making as error type in logback.xml so that it will not log everything.

Comment: @Sambit Alright, thanks this points me the right way to get rid of this annoyance :)

Comment: What is the reason you don't want this particular file to be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like i have solved this by putting  **logback.xml** and **logback-detailed.xml**

into  **src/main/resources/**

With data :

**logback.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <logger name="org.ethereum.*" level="OFF"/> Not sure if it really does anything. Bud works.
    <logger name="*" level="OFF"/>
</configuration>
```

**logback-details.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

</configuration>
```

Seems like it overriden what was configured by dependency and i got rid of file created by logback and additional files that were created periodically.

Comment: Bud be carefull, rather dont disable everything cause other dependencies also use it. And you will end up with no logs what so ever, sometimes it can be desired bud :D sometimes its not.